# Array Manipulation hackerrank solution python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

I am working on the HackerRank problem [Array Manipulation](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem):

> Starting with a 1-indexed array of zeros and a list of operations, for each operation add a value to each the array element between two given indices, inclusive. Once all operations have been performed, return the maximum value in the array.

My code works for most the cases, but the cases where `n` and `m` are huge numbers, I get a Runtime error in HackerRank and I don't know why.

NB: the same logic implemented in C++ worked and has been accepted.

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys
import logging

print("hello")
#
# Complete the 'arrayManipulation' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return a LONG_INTEGER.
# The function accepts following parameters:
#  1. INTEGER n
#  2. 2D_INTEGER_ARRAY queries
#

def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
    s = [0] *  (n+7)
    for query in queries :
        s[query[0]] += query[2]
        s[query[1]+1] += -1 * query[2]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        s[i] += s[i-1]
    max =  -1;
    for i in range(n+1):
        if(s[i] > max):
            max = s[i];
            
    return  max

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    nm = input().split()
    n = int(nm[0])
    m = int(nm[1])
    queries = []
    for _ in range(m):
        queries.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))
    result = arrayManipulation(n, queries)
    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')
    fpt`r.close()
```

I tried printing some details but it doesn't show in debug output

Comment: This problem is behind a login.  Can you summarize the problem?

Comment: Starting with a 1-indexed array of zeros and a list of operations, for each operation add a value to each the array element between two given indices, inclusive. Once all operations have been performed, return the maximum value in the array.

Comment: Please edit your question, so the challenge description is in the question. Also it would be nice if you would give feedback to the answers that were given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of updates your code has to perform is too large (at least for Python).

You can instead split the queries in start and stop events, and then sort those events. Finally iterate those events to get the maximum accumulated value.

```
from itertools import accumulate
 
def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
    return max(accumulate(value for _, value in 
             sorted([(first, value) for first, _, value in queries]
                  + [(last + 1, -value) for _, last, value in queries])
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ is fast enough that you can get away with being inefficient.  Python is slower and this algorithm is no longer good enough.

Instead of storing the data in an array of values, store in an array of deltas.  There are many ways of doing this.  Suppose that your array looks like:

```
A = [a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9]
```

Transform it into pairs `ai-aj` where `j` is the first previous number divisible by a higher power of 2.  Like this.

```
B = [a0, a1-a0, a2-a0, a3-a2, a4-a0, a5-a4, a6-a4, a7-a6, a8-a0, a9-a8]
  = [b0,    b1,    b2,    b3,    b4,    b5,    b6,    b7,    b8,    b9]
```

You can transform `B` back into `A` through a telescoping sum of higher powers.

```
A = [b0, b0+b1, b0+b2, b0+b2+b3, b0+b4, b0+b4+b5, b0+b4+b6, b0+b4+b6+b7, b0+b8, b0+b8+b9]
  = [a0, a0+b1, a0+b2,    a2+b3, a0+b4,    a4+b5,    a4+b6,       a6+b7, a0+b8,    a8+b9]
```

We can convert back and forth between these with `O(n)` work.

But suppose we get a query `[i, j, k]`.  In the `A` representation, this requires `O(j-i+1)` work.  In the `B` representation, this requires at most `O(log(n))` work.  (Starting at `i`, keep adding `+k` to the increasing powers of 2 until you hit `j`.  Then add `-k` to the increasing powers of `2` until you've hit double the top power of 2 in the range.)

You'll have to be careful to get the indexing right.  But with a lot of queries with a big range, it is a pretty big performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the Prefix Sum Technique in Arrays

```
def arrayManipulation_1(n, queries):

# Initialize the array
arr = [0 for i in range(n+1)]

# Perform the query operations
for a,b,k in queries:
    arr[a-1] += k
    arr[b] -= k
    # print(arr)

# find the maximum element
maxnum = temp = 0
for val in arr:
    temp += val
    maxnum = max(maxnum,temp)

return maxnum
```